# Getting all classes from one element and adding them to another element in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all classes from one element, then add them to another element created dynamically.  I was originally stuck on how to do this, but as I was typing out this question, I worked out a solution. However, it seems a bit verbose.  Is there a way to do this same thing more efficiently, i.e. with fewer lines of code?

```
    let classes = this.nextElementSibling.classList;      // get classes from target element
    classes += '';                                        // convert classlist object to string
    let class_array = classes.split(' ');                 // convert string to array
    const my_div = document.createElement('div');         // create a new div
    for(i=0; i<class_array.length; i++) {                 // loop through array and add classes to the div
      my_div.classList.add(class_array[i]);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `className` will give you a space-separated string of class names an element has. Just use that.

```
const my_div = document.createElement('div');
my_div.className = this.nextElementSibling.className;
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way, thank you. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me.